# can I partly execute the code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Can I partly execute the code in Visual Studio? I have a code and instead of doing the whole execution can I do it partly? For example a function

Comment: It's called a "unit test". Write test program running only this function. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible.

What you can do is feed the specific function you want to try with some parameters like:

```
private int Sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

You can write a code like:

```
int test = Sum(10, 12);
```

and use the debug to watch what happens.

Comment: I did that already, I was just wondering can I partly execute the code, it seems no.